# How can i pivot this table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to figure how to write a dynamic pivot sql statement. I need to calculate datewise sum( amt) per salesman where date is taken between dynamically inputed range

Here is my table.:

*Source Table*

```
╔Sman_name  date    amt

aaa        2014-09-20        100

bbb        2014-09-22        200

aaa       2014-09-20         150

aaa       2014-09-22         200
```

I should get the following result:

```
 2014-09-20      2014-09-21 2014-09-22

   aaa   250          0         200
   bbb    0           0        200
```

How to achieve this using pivot query?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a query which generates serial dates between two dates, which will be the source for the column names for the dynamic pivot.
Secondly since you need 0 for null values, for each dyncamic column an ISNULL check needs to to built.

Check the following solutions

```
DECLARE @startDate date = '2014-09-20'
DECLARE @endDate date = '2014-09-25'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dates NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- to add ISNULL(columnName,0) to return 0 if null
DECLARE @nullChecks NVARCHAR(MAX)
--CTE for generating serial dates
;WITH Dates([Date])
AS
(
    --Start with the first date
    SELECT @startDate 

    UNION ALL

    -- Loop by joining the CTE Dates, until the date < @endDate
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,Dates.[Date]) 
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Dates.[Date] < @endDate
)
SELECT @dates = COALESCE(@dates + '],[', '') + CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(10)),
    @nullChecks = COALESCE(@nullChecks + 'ISNULL([', '') + 
                    CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(10)) + '],0) AS ['+CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(10))+'] ,'
FROM Dates
--Append ISNULL condition in the beginnig
SET @nullChecks = 'ISNULL([' + SUBSTRING(@nullChecks,1,LEN(@nullChecks)-1)
SET @sql =' 
SELECT sman_name,' + @nullChecks + ' FROM yourTableName
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amt) FOR [date] IN ([' + @dates + '])
) As P;'

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: tx alot :)... very well explained...:)